# How to remove leading and trailing white spaces from input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, trim, removing-whitespace

I need to fix a bug in AngularJS application, which has many forms to submit data-

Every Text box in forms is accepting whitespaces(both leading and trailing) and saving them into the database. So in order to fix this I used `ng-trim="true"`, it worked and data is getting saved correctly in the back-end.

Problem: Even after using ng-trim when I click on save/update, the form UI shows the text with white-spaces not the trimmed data. It shows correct data only when I refresh the page.

Can anyone guide me.. what will be the approach to fix this?

P.S. - I'm new to both JavaScript and Angular!

Thanks

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: This is the version I'm using - 1.4.7

Comment: I think you should use ng-trim="false"(default is true) and when you are calling the save function to update the model by trimming the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using trim() method works fine, but is used in newer browsers.

```
    function removeWhitespaceUsingTrimMethod {
     
            var str = "    This is whitespace string for testing purpose     ";
            var wsr = str.trim();
            alert(wsr);
        }
```

Output:
This is whitespace string for testing purpose

From Docs:

```
(method) String.trim(): string
```

> Removes the leading and trailing white space and line terminator
> characters from a string.

2. Using replace() method – works in all browsers

Syntax:

testStr.replace(rgExp, replaceText);
str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

```
function removeWhitespaceUsingReplaceMethod {
         
            var str = "    This is whitespace string for testing purpose     ";
            var wsr = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
            alert( wsr);
    }
```

Output:
This is whitespace string for testing purpose

Answer (score 3):

Use `string = string.trim()` where `string` is the variable holding your string value.

Comment: I've one guess/doubt: the problem is not with trim function but with something else. I am able to trim  the values and save it correct in the database but the problem is when I click on save/update the data which appears on form is incorrect(means with leading and trailing whitespaces). It becomes correct when I refresh the page.

Comment: Please add your code to your question or create a plunker or fiddle showing the problem so we can better help you.

Comment: "(method) String.trim(): string
Removes the leading and trailing white space and line terminator characters from a string." The answer is valid

Answer (score 1):

When using reactive forms

```
  this.form.controls['email'].valueChanges
    .subscribe(x=>{
      if(x.includes(' ')){
        console.log('contains spaces')
        this.form.controls['email'].setValue(x.trim())
      }else{
        console.log('does not contain spaces')
      }
    })
```